# How to return the largest timestamp for a sort key from dynamodb table using Go APIs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table structure like this:

| column | type |
| --- | --- |
| bubbleId | String |
| bubbleLastUpdated | String |
| ... | ... |

`bubbleId` is my Primary Key and `bubbleLastUpdated` is my Sort Key

The ellipses(...) represent the rest of the data in the structure which doesn't pertain to this question.

**Using the expression builder where possible, how should the QueryInput object be built, such that the largest value for `bubbleLastUpdated` is returned?**

I'm using the following in my QueryInput object:

```
    results, err := d.dynamoClient.Query(&dynamodb.QueryInput{
        TableName: aws.String(tableName),
        ScanIndexForward: aws.Bool(false),
        Limit: aws.Int64(1),
    })
```

Of course, this returns an error saying there must be a `KeyConditionExpression` parameter in the request. I'm somewhat familiar with key expression builder, but I don't want to actually provide conditionals for these. Unfortunately, after a ton of searching, I've ended up here. I'm either looking for the wrong thing or missing something simple.

An example would be most helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you call primary key is actually called partition key. You have to specify at least the partition key to be able to use `query`.

If you don't have the partition key, then you can use `scan`, but it is inefficient, and you should consider redesigning the table, or adding `global secondary index (gsi)`.

You can use the partition key in the query like this:

```
    var queryInput = &dynamodb.QueryInput{
        TableName:        aws.String(tableName),
        ScanIndexForward: aws.Bool(false),
        Limit:            aws.Int64(1),
        KeyConditions: map[string]*dynamodb.Condition{
            "bubbleId": {
                ComparisonOperator: aws.String("EQ"),
                AttributeValueList: []*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                    {
                        S: aws.String("bubbleId"),
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }

    var resp, err = d.dynamoClient.Query(queryInput)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly, I believe I've been thinking about the 'partition key' incorrectly. For example, instead of having a table for multiple zoos which contain all of their animals. I should have one table with the 'zoo' as the partition key, which would separate all of the animals. And let's say the date is the last feeding of each animal. Then I could Query the last feeding of any zoo.

Comment: after finding the related doc it made sense https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.KeyConditions.html